# Create link between node

Tags: javascript, jointjs

I started with the JavaScript library Joint js, I want to dynamically create a link between two node already created by selecting the source node but without using the ports is that it is possible, thanks for your help

Sincerely yours

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: I just dynamically create the node am sorry for my english

Comment: NOBODY CAN HELP ME ???? :/ :/

Answer (score 1):

By dynamically, do you mean in Javascript?

If so, then you just need to use the link constructor, specifiying the source element (where the link starts from) and the target element (where it ends):

```
//say you have already got the source and target elements sourceEl and targetEl

var link = new joint.dia.Link({
   source: sourceEl,
   target: targetEl
});

graph.addCell(link);
```

Here [is a working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zxyuzg14/2/).

There is documentation for this on the JointJS website - for example, the hello world sample at http://www.jointjs.com/tutorial

Answer (score 1):

```
var link = new joint.dia.Link({
            source: { id: source.id },
            target: { id: target.id },
            vertices: [{ x: 400, y: 250 }],           
        }),
```